# Why doesn't Locale(String) constructor work in Java properly?

Tags: java, android, locale

Let's see the example code first:

```
Locale l1 = new Locale("fr_FR");
Locale l2 = new Locale("fr-FR");
Locale l3 = new Locale("fr_fr");
Locale l4 = new Locale("fr-fr");
Locale l5 = new Locale("fr", "FR");
Locale l6 = new Locale("fr", "fr");
Locale l7 = Locale.FRANCE;

System.out.println(l1.getDisplayCountry());
System.out.println(l2.getDisplayCountry());
System.out.println(l3.getDisplayCountry());
System.out.println(l4.getDisplayCountry());

System.out.println(l5.getDisplayCountry());
System.out.println(l6.getDisplayCountry());
System.out.println(l7.getDisplayCountry());


System.out.println("----------------");


NumberFormat nf1 = NumberFormat.getInstance(l1);
NumberFormat nf2 = NumberFormat.getInstance(l2);
NumberFormat nf3 = NumberFormat.getInstance(l3);
NumberFormat nf4 = NumberFormat.getInstance(l4);
NumberFormat nf5 = NumberFormat.getInstance(l5);
NumberFormat nf6 = NumberFormat.getInstance(l6);
NumberFormat nf7 = NumberFormat.getInstance(l7);

System.out.println(nf1.format(12345.678));
System.out.println(nf2.format(12345.678));
System.out.println(nf3.format(12345.678));
System.out.println(nf4.format(12345.678));
System.out.println(nf5.format(12345.678));
System.out.println(nf6.format(12345.678));
System.out.println(nf7.format(12345.678));
```

I'm testing `Locale(String)` constructor here because the results from `format()` method were wrong in my app. I used the same way as **l1**, the first line, but this doesn't work both on my desktop PC and android phones.
To be more precise, it works fine with Android TTS API, but fails on everything else.
If you see the code above, only the last three, **l5**, **l6**, and **l7** work correctly both on Windows and Android.

I don't get any error or exception messages but
**l1**, **l2**, **l3**, and **l4**'s `getDisplayCountry()` returns nothing and **nf1**, **nf2**, **nf3**, **nf4**'s `format()` returns just as Locale.US.

What's wrong with the first two?

Comment: You should probably be using `forLanguageTag(String languageTag)`. The constructor of Locale doesn't support IETF BCP 47 tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because *that* constructor **only** takes a language.

Note that [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) has [3 constructors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#constructor.summary):

```
Locale(String language)
Locale(String language, String country)
Locale(String language, String country, String variant)
```

Which means that valid calls are:

```
new Locale("fr")
new Locale("fr", "FR")
```

You can also use the [`Locale.forLanguageTag(String languageTag)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#forLanguageTag-java.lang.String-) method:

```
Locale.forLanguageTag("fr-FR") // must use '-' as separator
```

There is no method for getting a `Locale` from a `"fr_FR"` string (with '_' separator), which means that the string returned by [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#toString--) cannot be used to re-create the `Locale`. You must use [`toLanguageTag()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html#toLanguageTag--) to get a string for that purpose.

Comment: That's why... I made that stupid mistake for some reasons. Firstly I thought it would be the same as C#'s CultureInfo, and I also saw someone else did the same thing in Java too. Moreover, I don't know why but Android TTS worked with my stupid code, so never thought I did something wrong. Thanks Andreas!